# Change the getResult array key for the primary key value

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to change the array key values for the getResult() in Doctrine2?

Example:

`$qb->select('t.id, t.name')->from('Table', 't');`

When I print this, I get, which is not what I wanted:

`print_r($qb->getQuery()->getResult()); 


//Print result: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 20 [name] => Name1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 21 [percentagem] => Name2 ) )`

What I want is:

`Array ( [20] => Array ( [id] => 20 [name] => Name1 ) [21] => Array ( [id] => 21 [percentagem] => Name2 ) )`

Suggestions, hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I'm actually very happy about how cool this thing is:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQuery('
            SELECT user FROM UserBundle:User user
            INDEX BY user.id
            WHERE user.id = 1
            '
        );
```

> The INDEX BY construct is nothing that directly translates into SQL
>   but that affects object and array hydration. After each FROM and JOIN
>   clause you specify by which field this class should be indexed in the
>   result. By default a result is incremented by numerical keys starting
>   with 0. However with INDEX BY you can specify any other column to be
>   the key of your result, it really only makes sense with primary or
>   unique fields though.

Source: [Doctrine ORM 2 Documentation Using INDEX BY](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#using-index-by)

- Please use INDEX BY prior to WHERE

Comment: Exciting approach but it doesn't seem to work with MySql 5.6.16.  Should it?

Comment: @MatthewT.Baker It's not SQL, it is DQL and as mentioned, does not translate to anything in the resulting SQL query.

Answer (score 21):

However, for the sake of completeness, you can do the same with the query builder as shown below:

```php
$queryBuilder = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder
    ->select('user')
    ->from('UserBundle:User', 'user', 'user.id')
    ->where('user.id = :userId')
    ->setParameter('userId', $userId)
;

var_dump(
    $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getArrayResult()
);
```

As you can see the **index by** option is available as the third parameter of the query builder `from` method:

```php
/**
 * Creates and adds a query root corresponding to the entity identified by the given alias,
 * forming a cartesian product with any existing query roots.
 *
 * <code>
 *     $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder()
 *         ->select('u')
 *         ->from('User', 'u')
 * </code>
 *
 * @param string $from    The class name.
 * @param string $alias   The alias of the class.
 * @param string $indexBy The index for the from.
 *
 * @return QueryBuilder This QueryBuilder instance.
 */
public function from($from, $alias, $indexBy = null)
{
    return $this->add('from', new Expr\From($from, $alias, $indexBy), true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the 3-rd parameter of `->from(entity, alias, indexBy)`

So, instead

```
$qb->select('t.id, t.name')->from('Table', 't');
```

use

```
$qb->select('t.id, t.name')->from('Table', 't', 'Table.id');
```

PS:
@Francesco-Casula wrote good answer with little more details, well.