# Doctrine: key result array on an id

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

Using Doctrine:

```
$result = array(
    array('user_id'=>1, 'name'=>'foo'),
    array('user_id'=>2, 'name'=>'bar'),
);

$expected = array(
    1 => array('user_id'=>1, 'name'=>'foo'),
    2 => array('user_id'=>2, 'name'=>'bar'),
);
```

Is it possible to somehow key/index the result array on some field via **Doctrine\ORM\Query**?

Comment: I think you need a extra foreach for it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change the getResult array key for the primary key value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327798/change-the-getresult-array-key-for-the-primary-key-value)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use

```
INDEX BY t.userId
```

where t is your table/entity alias